# ERC721 Smart Contract - transfer tokens as the contract owners

Tags: erc-721

This is the hypothetic use case I came up to learn about smart contract programming.

I am trying to create a ERC721 Smart Contract that would mint tokens for photographers who want to sell their work.  The photographer uploads a picture and I put it somewhere and include that link as the tokenURI for my UniquePhotoNFT.

When I mint a new token of UniquePhotoNFT, it has an ID (1,2,3,4, etc) with all different token URIs. All those tokens belong to me as I am holding all those tokens for my users (so they don't need to deal with any of the blockchain staff).

When someone comes to buy a UniquePhotoNFT with token id 3, I can easily transfer that token 3 to the buyer's address.  However, if the new owner decides to sell the same token to someone else, how can I make the transfer on their behalf?  It won't let me do it because as the contract owner, I am not the token owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) provides a function `isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator)`

> Query if an address is an authorized operator for another address

That function can be used enable a special address to always be authorized to operate on the NFTs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a marketplace contract. Seller should approve this token to your marketplace. If you verified your marketplace contract, that won't be a problem. Because contract addresses don't have private key. Here is the steps:

1. Seller approve token to marketplace.
2. Seller calls setForSale function from marketplace.
3. Buyer can come and buy tokens from market (don't forget to check getApproved).

Comment: What would be a good example of marketplace contract?

Comment: You can look rarible or opensea's contracts. I recommend you to look Rarible's docs.